# Cytoscape.js & cose-bilkent: optimal parameters for preventing node & edge overlapping

Tags: cytoscape.js

I need to draw relatively small (max 20 nodes) network graphs with Cytoscape.js. Most of the time the graphs look nice, but sometimes there are problems. Sometimes nodes are located too close or there are other issues. Below a couple of examples:

[image: example 1]

[image: example 2]

Often some edges also overlap, even though it should not be difficult to lay out the nodes so that no overlapping occurs.

I've been experimenting with the parameters, however since there are so many variables it has been very difficult to find out an optimal combination.

Parameters I'm using ATM:

```
cy.layout({
  name: "cose-bilkent",
  animate: false,
  idealEdgeLength: 30,
  quality: "proof",
  randomize: false,
  nodeDimensionsIncludeLabels: true,
  nodeRepulsion: 7000,
  edgeElasticity: 0.45,
  nestingFactor: 0.1,
  numIter: 30000,
  gravity: 0.25,
  tile: true
}).run();
```

What should I tweak?

EDIT:

A couple of example images to Stephan (please see the comment):

[image: demo 1]
[image: demo 2]

Comment: The cose layout has a built in spring mechanism, so if you stick to the [demo](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-cose-bilkent/blob/master/demo.html), you should be just fine, right?

Comment: @StephanT. unfortunately the same issues exist with the demo. I added a couple of examples to the question.

Comment: It would help a lot if you were to add your code, so that we can use that as a starting point, thanks :D

Comment: Well, the demo you pointed out is a good starting point.

Answer (score 3):

Neither cose-bilkent nor fcose has a mechanism to prevent edge overlaps. It is actually hard to achieve in force-directed layout algorithms. On the other hand, these two algorithms try to prevent node overlaps as far as possible, but it can happen rarely especially if the graph is dense.

One way to reduce the chance of overlap is to increase the `idealEdgeLength` parameter in both algorithms which will keep the nodes more seperate. Also use `randomize: true` if there is no reason to prevent applying layout from scratch. But I suggest you use fcose algorithm if your graph is planar (or near-planar) because fcose usually does a better job in providing plane embeddings of planar graphs.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I tested also with fcose. If I use randomize: false, it provides worse graphs than cose-bilkent. With randomize: true the graphs are much better. However, in our application the same graph must be shown simultaneously for several users and thus randomization is not possible.

Comment: Btw, in a legacy application we used Springy and it almost never overlaps edges http://getspringy.com/demo.html

I'm aware that springy layout is also available for Cytoscape, but I wasn't satisfied with it's results.